# Speeding up correlated query with count distinct

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I have a table `posts` that looks like:

```
id    | user_id | created_at
```

I want a query that returns how many different users have posted every day during the last previous 60 days to that day. So the result would look something like:

```
date       | count
2017-12-9  | 28
2017-12-10 | 25 (there were 25 different users posting during the previous 60 days to 2017-12-10)
```

I'm trying to this using correlated subqueries in MySQL, but performance is awful no matter the indexes I try. My current query looks like:

```
SELECT
  DATE(orig_posts.created_at) as date,
  (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT(posts.user_id))
    FROM
        posts
    WHERE
        posts.created_at BETWEEN (orig_posts.created_at - INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND orig_posts.created_at
  ) as count
FROM
  posts as orig_posts
WHERE
  orig_posts.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
GROUP BY
  DATE(orig_posts.created_at)
```

After explaining the query, the culprit seems to be the `COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))` but I cannot come up with a better performant alternative of this query. Explain output is:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type  | possible_keys                                                                      | key            | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                                     |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | orig_posts    | range | created_at_idx,created_at_plus_type_idx,created_at_plus_type_plus_user_id_idx      | created_at_idx | 5       | NULL |  12179 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | posts         | ALL   | created_at_idx,created_at_plus_type_idx,created_at_plus_type_plus_user_id_idx      | NULL           | NULL    | NULL | 548653 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x580)          |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your explain output?

Comment: I've just added it

Comment: Are you not getting subquery returned more than one value?

Comment: Sorry, I posted an intermediate attempt I had made, I've just fixed the query. Yes, I've tried to write it in a different way without any luck.

Comment: Just a thought, try removing all indexes (except for your PK), and only add an index on the created_at column. I've found if you over-index a table, it can hinder performance.

Comment: Thanks, I've just removed all and left that and didn't make any difference.